# Install a game from Steam to ScummVM

Tags: steam, android, scummvm

I bought a game on Steam and I would like to play it in ScummVM (on an Android device).
I've installed the game on my PC and copied the files (*.LFL) but ScummVM does not recognize them.

Is there a way to accomplish it?